# Matplotlib does not print any plot on Databricks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, azure-databricks

```
%matplotlib inline
corr = df.corr()
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
ax = sns.heatmap(
    corr, 
    vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,
    cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=500),
    linewidths=.50, 
    cbar_kws={"shrink": .7},
    square=True
)

ax.set_xticklabels(
    ax.get_xticklabels(),
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right'
);
plt.show()
```

This code is does not give any plot display on azure data bricks, only displays

```
<Figure size 1100x900 with 2 Axes>
```

whereas the same code worked fine and displayed a corr plot earlier, not sure whats going wrong here.
I get the same output even when I try this.

```
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

cmap = sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, as_cmap=True)

sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=0.3, center=0,
            square=True, linewidths=.1, cbar_kws={"shrink": .7})
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like an issue with the matplotlib modules above `3.3.0`.

> To know the exact reason, I would suggest you to report here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues

As per the test from our end, you will experience the following error message with the matplotlib modules above `3.3.0`.

[image]

If you have installed matplotlib modules above `3.3.0`, I would suggest you to use matplotlib modules below `3.2.2`.

[image]

Once you have installed `matplotlib==3.2.2`, I'm able to successfully display the plot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> It perhaps may have to do with your Databricks runtime
> https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/matplotlib.html

For an alternative, Try `display(plt.show())` if inline doesn't seem to work